# Need performant way to add commas to years with 5 digits

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, date, format

I'm building a site and considering time strings representative of the Human Era, with a year 0 starting 12019 years ago. This means all my timestamps have an extra digit on them. (Here's a link to a video explaining why we would do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaB41TtgS54 )

I think it would look nicer if there were a comma after the first 1 or 2 digits.

I've written something up myself but it's more lines of code than I'd like and don't have the time to focus on refactoring it right now. I'd like to, as it's important, but I bet someone with a higher skill level could achieve this faster than I could.

Here's my current function. It loads on every page a lot of times.

```php
// Uses Wordpress post dates
$post->date_posted = get_human_year($post->post_date);

function get_human_year($date) {
  $a = new \DateTime($date);
  $b = new \DateTime;

  $days_ago = $a->diff($b)->days; // => 1

  if($days_ago == 0){
    $date_str = "today";
  } else if ($days_ago == 1) {
    $date_str = "yesterday";
  } else {
    $date_str = "{$days_ago} days ago";
  }

  $string = date('M d, Y', strtotime($date .' + 10000 years')) . " ({$date_str})";
  $pattern = '/[0-9]{4,5}/i';
  if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $match)) {
    $year = (int)$match[0];
    $hyear = number_format($year, 0, '.', ',');
    return(str_replace($year, $hyear, $string));

  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

So the above code outputs something like

> Aug 25, 12,019 (29 days ago)

The (x days ago) functionality will eventually list more than days

Assuming this is going to end up in a successful product operating at scale, it represents a big change in how time is parsed. I'd love to see this more performant and benchmarked at high quantities. (I would be using caching to store the values for a specific post once acquired)

Thanks for your help or for any insight provided.

Comment: Please don't do this.

Comment: If you must do this for whatever comical and contrived reason then use [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) instead of regex because regex is heavy.

Comment: Lines of code and performance are very different things. What makes you think this isn't performant enough? What is your current benchmark? How many strings per page is this processing? More details seem necessary.